# What datasets exist for co-clustering?

Tags: matlab, dataset, cluster-analysis

I am looking for new datasets of documents, from which to extract the matrix terms-documents, to perform co-clustering algorithms.

I am looking forsingle-label datasets only and prefer free access ones.

I already know the following datasets.: 
CSTR
WebKB4
Newsgroups
Reuters
K1A, K1B, wap (WebACE Project)

Do you know of any others?

You also know of the new co-clustering algorithms created in the last two years?

thanks

Comment: why [tag:matlab] tag?

Answer (score 0):

For datasets, see experiments section of [this work](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2903).

For new algorithms see:

- [Vitaladevuni and Basri](http://www.wisdom.weizmann.ac.il/~ronen/papers/Vitaladevuni%20Basri%20-%20Co-Clustering%20of%20Image%20Segments%20Using%20Convex%20Optimization%20Applied%20to%20EM%20Neuronal%20Reconstruction.pdf) CVPR 2010
- [Bagon and Galun](http://arxiv.org/abs/1112.2903) arXiv 2011.
- [Yarkony et al](http://arxiv.org/abs/1208.0378) ECCV 2012
- [Kim et al](http://www.nowozin.net/sebastian/papers/kim2011clustering.pdf) NIPS 2011
- [Andres et al](http://hci.iwr.uni-heidelberg.de/publications/mip/techrep/andres_12_globally.pdf) ECCV 2012

Just to name a few.

Comment: thanks but for this experiment they use face dataset and i need documents datasets. Thanks.

Comment: @Gaberiele - if your only concern is comparing Co-clustering algorithms, then why do you care if the underlying data comes from documents or images?

Comment: I use algorithm non-negative matrix tri-factorization for co-clustering and i must use matrix terms-documents because the algoritm use that.